# Flex Datagrid Edit event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

in my flex application im  using a datagrid with 5 columns...in which 3 are editable...if i add an item to the grid, when i hit enter, the cursor position moves in the grid from right to left in Datagrid cells .. by repeating for more items...it works....after adding 20 items the cursor... moves vertically editable cells...ie:from top to down its moving when i hit enter...
  how to solve this??

heres my code for grid

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="Do" dataProvider="{GrdPrvider}" keyDown="Do_keyDownHandler(event)" 
                             headerHeight="22" resizeEffect="resize" editable="true" sortExpertMode="true" lockedColumnCount="3" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" width="95%" height="160" x="0" y="10"><mx:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="#" editable="false" width="40" dataField="SerialNo" sortCompareFunction="SiNoCompare" />
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Desc" editable="false" labelFunction="dgLableFunction" sortCompareFunction="sortableDesc" width="250"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Fos" sortable="false" editable="true" width="40"> <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="gos" sortable="false" editable="true" width="40">
```

For Key down event the function as below..

```
protected function Do_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {


            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            {
                if(Do.columns[colIdx].editable && event.currentTarget.selectedIndex <= Do.columnCount)
                {

                    var cols:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(Do.columns);
                    var nxtGet:Boolean = false;
                    for(var i:String in cols)
                    {
                        if((int(i) > colIdx) && Do.columns[i].editable && (!nxtGet))
                        {
                            colIdx = int(i);                
                            nxtGet = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(nxtGet)
                    {
                        Do.editedItemPosition ={rowIndex: event.currentTarget.selectedIndex, columnIndex: colIdx};
                        event.preventDefault();                 
                        Do.dataProvider.refresh();  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(var r:String in  Do.columns)
                        {
                            if(Do.columns[r].headerText == "Fos")
                            {
                                colIdx = parseInt(r);
                            }
                        }               
                        Do.editedItemPosition ={rowIndex: event.currentTarget.selectedIndex+1, columnIndex: colIdx};
                        event.preventDefault();                 
                        Do.dataProvider.refresh();  
                    }

                } 

            }
        }
```